# Run inner query once, use results for math in outer query

Tags: mysql

Aloha,

I need to run a simple (`SELECT * FROM tbl1 WHERE Col1=x`) then use the single row that results from this query to perform math on another query. For example, the outer query could be `SELECT tbl2.col4 * tbl1.col5 AS firstResult`

Basically, `tbl1` is full of numeric statistical weights that I need to use to multiply on the values in `tbl2`. the query on `tbl1` will only ever return 1 row.

I would be perfectly happy joining the resulting tbl1 row to all returned `tbl2` rows and then doing math, but I have no join values in the tables. I tried to add a `'1' AS JoinID` to both tables, but that didn't work either.

Thanks guys,
Chris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing came to my mind was to use something like this:

```
select tbl2.col4 * tbl1x.col5 from tbl2, (select * from tbl1 where col1 = x) as tbl1x;
```

if I'm getting your question right.

Comment: Thanks Mike. Can't believe I over looked that.